Lie derivative of 1 form
I want to derive $\mathcal{L}_X (\omega) = (i_x d + d i_x) \omega$ for 1-form. I read
Lie derivative of 1-form
and it makes sense but I don't kmeow why my thing is not working. What I tried was
$$
(\mathcal{L}_X (\omega))(Y) 
= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{(\phi_t^{\star} \omega) (Y) - \omega (Y)}{t} \\
= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\omega ((\phi_t)_{\star} Y - Y)}{t} \\
= -\omega (\mathcal{L}_X Y) \\
= -\omega ([X, Y])
$$
From here I used coordinate basis
$$
(\mathcal{L}_X (\omega))(Y) 
= (\mathcal{L}_X (\omega))_{\mu} dx^{\mu}(Y^{\nu} \partial_{\nu}) = (\mathcal{L}_X (\omega))_{\mu}Y^{\mu} \\
-\omega ([X, Y]) 
= -\omega_{\mu} dx^{\mu} (X^{\nu} (\partial_{\nu} Y^{\rho}) \partial_{\rho} - Y^{\rho} (\partial_{\rho} Y^{\nu}) \partial_{\nu} ) \\
= -\omega_{\mu} X^{\nu} (\partial_{\nu} Y^{\mu}) + \omega_{\mu} X^{\nu} (\partial_{\nu} Y^{\mu}) 
$$
Where did I make a mistake?

I guess my question reduces to this:
why does it hold that
$$
\mathcal{L}_X (\omega Y) = \mathcal{L}_X (\omega) Y + \omega \mathcal{L}_X (Y)
$$

A derivation of this formula can be found in [1] p. 203. Nakahara does not apply $\omega$ to a vector field $Y,.$ He rather makes sure that the expressions we subtract in the differentiation are elements on the same cotangent space $T^_xM,.$ The expression he starts with is in your notation
$$
{\cal L}X\omega=\lim{t\to 0}\frac{\phi_t^\omega|_{\phi_t(x)}-\omega|_x}{t},.
$$
[1] M. Nakahara,  Geometry Topology and Physics.

@Kurt I hope the LHS is evaluated somewhere …

@TedShifrin at $x$ for sure. Looks like a typo in my copy of [1].

Look carefully at the second line of your coordinate computation. With regard to your final question, think of it as the product rule. But, as Kurt says, be very careful going to the second line of your first computation; where is everything evaluated? How do you reduce to the value of $\omega$ at the given point, rather than using its values nearby?
